# Esper: find earliest event within time after a trigger event arrives

Tags: esper

My event stream generally contains an open event followed by a close event. Let's call them `O` and `C`, correspndingly. However, there are two particulars:

1. `O` may be followed by one or more `O` before `C` arrives
2. `C` may be missing completely (see below)

It is assumed that `C` should arrive not later than within time `T` after some `O`. Otherwise, `C` is considered missing. When a `C` eventually arrives, all open `O`s arrived earlier than `T` from this `C` are considered orphans and are of no interest.

I want esper to fire each pair of `O` followed by `C`, where earliest `O` not farther then `T` from `C` is selected. Any `O`s in between as well as before selected `O` are skipped.

For example,

`O1 O2 O3 ... C`

should select `(O1,C)` if `datediff(O1, C) < T`

should select `(O2,C)` if above is false and `datediff(O2, C) < T`

etc.

A lost my temper in approaching this problem. Looks like my mind is not compatible with esper. Your help is very appritiated.

Answer (score 0):

This could be something like below, the idea is that when Event arrives we want to look at the last 1 minute of events and find the first one that matches the time diff. Have a second statement filter out those without matches, if that is desired.

insert into Pair
select *, (select window(*).firstOf(v => v.time - e2.time < T) from Event.win:time(1 min) as e1) as matched
from Event as e2

select * from Pair where matched is not null

Comment: First of all, thank you for the response,
Having your idea in mind, I tried the following query:
`select (select first(*) from O.win:time(1 hour)), c.* from C c;`
It outputs earliest `O` within hour from `C`. Unfortunately, it continues to report earliest `O` when subsequent pairs of `O` followed by `C` arrives within same hour. That is, for the following series where all events arrived within 1 hour:
`O1 O2 C1 O3 C2`
, it returns pairs `(O1,C1)` and `(O1, C2)`. While what I want is `(O1,C1), (O3,C2)`. There must be some means to reset time window of arriving `O`s, when `C` arrives...